# default error handler when multiple calls to next(error)

Tags: node.js, express, error-handling

The [express doc](https://expressjs.com/en/guide/error-handling.html) says:

> Note that the default error handler can get triggered if you call
> next() with an error in your code more than once, even if custom error
> handling middleware is in place.

I think it means if we call `next(error)` inside our **custom error handler**, then the control passes on to next error handler (which may be the express' default one if we already has not registered more custom error handlers).

Is my understanding correct?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you have understood it correctly. However, it is not useful to call the **default error handler** inside the **custom error handler** as the only purpose of the **custom error handler** is to send the errors to the user according to you i.e. in your format.

You can implement a custom **global error handler** by defining an **error-handling middleware** after all the `app.use` calls and in the callback function, you can create your own logic like sending different errors in `dev` or `prod` environment. You can also set up different user-friendly messages.

```js
app.use(function (err, req, res, next) {
  err.statusCode = err.statusCode || 500;
  err.status = err.status || 'error';

  if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development') {
    // a custom function for sending dev errors
    sendErrorDev(err, res);
  } else if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {
    // logic for creating different user-friendly errors 
    sendErrorProd(error, res);
  }
})
```

And in both `sendErrorDev` and `sendErrorProd` functions, you can send the errors by the `res` object.